# Best way to organise Javascript code in Phonegap apps

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Phonegap apps are usually different from general web sites, even if they are written with the same language.

Main differences:

- a Phonegap app loads main pages from local file
- many web frameworks for mobiles (like jQuery Mobile) usually load a single html file and then programmatically change pages.

So I think it's outdated the common suggestion of put code on external JS file. Is it true?
What's the best way to organize the code so it will be fast to load and easily maintainable? (e.g. do you separate code that concerns the view and code that concerns the data?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with jQueryMobile I have many html files. Sometimes we're loading a portion of content from another html file using the jQueryMobile mechanism of loading just a particular #id from the html file. In many apps the data is being loaded from an external site and being inserted into the content from the local files. If I do load any data locally I use a data subfolder unless I'm loading from local storage.

Given that, here is my typical structure of my www folder:

```
www (all my views go in this main folder)
  data (any local files that will be loaded for insertion into my views)
  js (all my phonegap plugins and jquery source goes here)
  styles (css for jquery, local views, etc)
  images (local images for my views
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Just a question: do you separate code that concerns the view (e.g. a function that refresh a listview) from the code that concerns the data (e.g. fetching the data that will fill the listview)? Thank you

Comment: @micred, more often I do not separate that code, but it will depend on how large your application is. With some very large applications I have separated the JS code into many different files, each file dealing with a distinct area of functionality within the app. I think this will be different for different apps. With a smaller app keeping all your code in the same js file will probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap apps are generally web-apps using advanced integration points. The content is still rendered in a WebView which is not very different from system browser...

There is no standard on organizing the code of your application but most advices for web-apps are a good fit for Phonegap apps too...